# RxJS missing operator errors in browser but not in the Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs

I have strange problem. I had existing `Angular4` project managed under `Angular-CLI` with `RxJS` library. After updating `RxJS` library to version `5.5.2` project starts to have problems with `Observable` operators. The Errors in `Google Chrome` are like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.apiService.request(...).switchMap is not a function
```

I know I can fix this with:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

But problem is with IDE in this case `Visual Studio Code`. It just not shows which operator imports missing. The only way I found so far to detect missing operators is to run application and check all features of the app in the browser with `Developer Console` opened waiting for this kind of errors. So I have two questions.

- Is there any better way to detect missing operators in my updated project? Why doesn't the build process catch the fact that the operator is missing?
- Is there any way that I can setup `Visual Studio Code` to show me this kind of errors before I push some changes and discover them in the browser? Syntax completion in this IDE is even working with not imported operators, which I think is wrong.

I'm attaching output from `ng -v`:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.5.3
Node: 6.11.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/cli: 1.5.3
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.33
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.21
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.37
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.7
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.8.1
```

And output from `npm list --depth=0`

```
├── @angular/animations@4.4.6
├── @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12
├── @angular/cli@1.5.3
├── @angular/common@4.4.6
├── @angular/compiler@4.4.6
├── @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6
├── @angular/core@4.4.6
├── @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.8
├── @angular/forms@4.4.6
├── @angular/http@4.4.6
├── @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12
├── @angular/platform-browser@4.4.6
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.6
├── @angular/platform-server@4.4.6
├── @angular/router@4.4.6
├── @types/hammerjs@2.0.34
├── @types/jasmine@2.5.45
├── @types/node@6.0.78
├── ag-grid@13.3.1
├── ag-grid-angular@13.3.0
├── classlist.js@1.1.20150312
├── codelyzer@3.0.1
├── core-js@2.4.1
├── hammerjs@2.0.8
├── i18n-iso-countries@3.2.2
├── jasmine-core@2.6.4
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@4.1.1
├── karma@1.7.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.1.1
├── karma-cli@1.0.1
├── karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter@1.3.0
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.0
├── karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
├── protractor@5.1.2
├── rxjs@5.5.2
├── ts-node@3.0.6
├── tslint@5.3.2
├── typescript@2.3.4
├── web-animations-js@2.3.1
└── zone.js@0.8.12
```

Comment: If you are going to use the prototype-patching operator imports, you might find this useful: [rxjs-tslint-rules](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules). These sorts of problems are why the new, [lettable/pipeable operators are preferred](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody have similar problem as mine.

The problem was related to importing in some of the *.ts files.
For example if You are importing some object like that:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

It is wrong because then `Visual Studio Code` will not inform you about missing operators. The same with `ng serve`.

If you import like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Then `Visual Studio Code` and `ng serve` will inform You about missing operators. So be aware if You're importing `from 'rxjs'` directly. It is better to refactor all your code that contains imports `from 'rxjs'` to something like `from 'rxjs/Observable'` etc...

Answer (score 0):

I get typescript reference checking with rxjs added operators.

Try setting `"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true` (File/Preferences/Settings).

A couple of other settings that may be relevent

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true (with this off, rxjs reference errors aren't shown)
"javascript.validate.enable": true
```

Ref [Extensions using CodeLens](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup)

You can see all errors in the Problems tab (Ctrl+Shift+M).

---

Another trick is to have all your rxjs imports in a top level file and import it into app.module.

```
import './rxjs-extensions';
```

**rxjs-extensions.js**

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/defaultIfEmpty';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/concat';
...

import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I found problem and I described it in the answer to my own question. It was related to the way that I was importing stuff from `rxjs` library. Your hint with `rxjs-extensions` file is very clever :)